# In Flow, how do you annotate "this.keyword" (not Props or State) on the Component?

Tags: flowtype

```
type Props = {
  loading: boolean,
  posts: PostNode,
  loadMoreEntries: () => PostFeed,
  showActionSheetWithOptions: () => Function,
  deletePost: (postId: string) => PostNode,
}

type State = {
  selectedIndex: number,
}

class Discussions extends Component {
  props: Props;
  state: State;

  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);

    this.keyword = '';

    this.state = {
      selectedIndex: 1,
    };
  }
...
```

In this case, I'm referring to `this.keyword` in the constructor, a property on the Component that is neither props nor state.

Comment: You've already annotated the other two. You'd annotate keyword the same way `keyword: string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
props: Props;
state: State;
```

are the annotations for `state` and `props`. You'd annotate `keyword` the same way with `keyword: string;`.